# Plotting a set of parameters

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the equations that describe the Cartesian locations of Bi-Cylinder coordinates. The equations are as follows:

```
x==(1.5 Sinh[n])/(Cosh[n]-Cos[p])   
y==(1.5 Sin[p])/(Cosh[n]-Cos[p])
```

I keep getting the following error

> Options expected(instead of {p,0,2 pi}) in position 2 of
>   Plot[{x,y},{n,-1,1},{p,0,2 pi},PlotRange All] an option must be a rule
>   or a set of rules

I need help in understanding the error and how to rectify the situation and get the program to run correctly.

Comment: 1) Use `Pi`, not `pi`. *Mathematica* is case-sensitive. 2) What are you trying to plot exactly?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to visualize, but I like how `ParametricPlot[{(1.5 Sinh[n])/(Cosh[n] - 
     Cos[p]), (1.5 Sin[p])/(Cosh[n] - Cos[p])}, {n, -1, 1}, {p, 0, 
  2 Pi}]` looks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using approach suggested by @Mikado except `Table` is moved inside of `ParametricPlot`

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[
   Tooltip[{
     (1.5 Sinh[n])/(Cosh[n] - Cos[p]),
     (1.5 Sin[p])/(Cosh[n] - Cos[p])},
    n],
   {n, -1, 1, 2/7}],
 {p, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Range[-1, 1, 2/7]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ParametricPlot`.  For example

```
Show[Table[ParametricPlot[{(1.5 Sinh[n])/(Cosh[n] - 
   Cos[p]), (1.5 Sin[p])/(Cosh[n] - Cos[p])}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {n, -1, 1, 2/7}]]
```

gives

[image]